# Getting unique items from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript object that is created dynamically from a database call that looks like the following:

```
{
  department: 'Fraud',
  location: 'APAC'
},
{
  department: 'Disputes',
  location: 'APAC'
},
{
 department: 'Fraud',
 location: 'EMEA'   
}
```

This object is created by the following:

```
$(data).find('areas > option').each(function(){

    // Define data
    areas = $(this);

   // Define our vars
   department = $(areas).find('departmentDesc').text();
   areaDesc = $(areas).find('areaDesc').text();

   // Push items to our object
   impactedAreasArray.push({area: areaDesc, department: department});
});
```

What I am trying to do is check this object to see if there is more than 5 items using the following:

```
if(impactedAreasArray.length > 5){
  // If so, I want to get all of the unique areas and store them in an array
}else{
  // If not, I want to get all of the unique departments and store them in an array
}
```

I was going to go the route of looping over the object again and pushing them to another array if they don't already exist in it but it seemed inefficient and I was wondering if this could be done with mapping or a more elegant solution.

The point of this is if 25 departments are selected, I only want to show the regions that are impacted rather than list out all 25 of them. Where as if there were only 4 departments impacted, its a short enough list to just show the 4 departments.

Comment: Your plan seems fine.  I don't see a problem with it.

Comment: Use the values as the property names of an object, since property names must be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use objects whose properties are the department and location names. This will automatically make them unique.

```
var locations = {};
var departments = {};
impactedAreasArray = [];

$(data).find('areas > option').each(function(){

    // Define data
    areas = $(this);

   // Define our vars
   department = $(areas).find('departmentDesc').text();
   areaDesc = $(areas).find('areaDesc').text();

   // Push items to our object
   impactedAreasArray.push({area: areaDesc, department: department});
   locations[areaDesc] = true;
   departments[department] = true;
});
```

If you want them as arrays, you can then do:

```
locations = Object.keys(locations);
departments = Object.keys(departments);
```

Comment: I think this will work great actually. The one issue I'm having (probably doing it wrong) is trying to convert that to a comma separate string which I thought would be `Object.keys(areas).split(',');` Is that not correct?

Comment: You want `join`, not `split`.

Comment: Isn't the function of those two operations obvious from their names?

Comment: That's what I needed I just needed to then take that array of data and append it to the DOM as a comma separated string. Everything works as expected; I appreciate it!